# Class not found exception "java.time.temporal.TemporalField" when connecting to jdbc:postgresql from Matlab

Tags: postgresql, matlab, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database from Matlab. This is my code:

```
javaclasspath('/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc4.jar');
properties = java.util.Properties;
properties.setProperty('user', '********');
properties.setProperty('password', '********');
driver = org.postgresql.Driver;
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DBNAME';
connection = driver.connect(url, properties)
```

I get the following exception:

```
Error using org.postgresql.Driver/connect
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/temporal/TemporalField
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.temporal.TemporalField
<SNIP>
```

I'm running Matlab R2012a on Debian. Everything was installed from the testing repository. Java is openjdk version "1.8.0_144" and PostgreSQL is 9.6.5-1.

Comment: Which version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver are you using? Note that the exception itself suggests you are not actually using Java 8, as `java.time.temporal.TemporalField` is most definitely part of Java 8.

Comment: Ah, that's it. MATLAB itself is using its own Java 1.6 JRE, not the JDK that I have installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't use the jdk 1.8.

See [same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008094/http-status-500-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-time-temporal-temporalfie)

Could you try to execute java -version to be sure?

[edit]

This error happens because Matlab 2012 does not use Java 8. To confirm, run this in the Matlab shell, not in your system terminal:

```
java -version
```

It is posible to make Matlab use a different JDK, but this can cause more problems than it solves. The better solution is to get the PostgreSQL JDBC 4.0, which is suitable for Java 6.

Direct link: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.4.jre6.jar

Comment: It will return `openjdk version "1.8.0_144"` when I run from the terminal (which I thought was the proper way to check). But when I do the same from the Matlab shell, it returns `Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems <SNIP>` (which I just discovered).

Comment: You can modify this see the documentation : https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/configure-your-java-environment.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize what the problem was! But I found it better to just get a driver compatible with Java 6.